# The / route pattern always shows me the Symfony welcome page instead of my controller

Tags: apache, symfony, routes

I made a "/" pattern in my routes:

```
acme_store_index:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeStoreBundle:Default:index}
```

with the following action:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $message = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Message')
    ->findAll();

    return $this->render(
    'AcmeStoreBundle:Default:index.html.twig',
    array('message' => $message)
    );      
}
```

I also have set in Apache a vhost that declares as index page of localhost the file app_dev.php. (this way I don't have to include it in my urls all the time when I'm doing ajax calls etc)

Why is my / route ignored?

Comment: check in `app/config/routing_dev.yml` and remove the routing entries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem myself..

There was a / route declared in my AcmeDemoBundle:

```
_welcome:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:index }
```

inside the /app/config/routing_dev.yml file. I deleted it and I got my own index.

Comment: If you have not already done, follow [Getting started with Symfony](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard#4-getting-started-with-symfony) to delete the demo bundle

Comment: Do you know by chance how to remove welcome route in Symfony 6? There is nothing like this, I can't find it

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody is struggling with this in a newer version. As of Symfony 6 it seems like the welcome page is always going to be showed unless to define a `/` route.

It actually clearly states

> You're seeing this page because you haven't configured any homepage
> URL

If you set `APP_ENV=prod` the welcome page won't be returned. Instead you'll get a `NotFoundHttpException` and 500 page returned to the browser.

Comment: Seems to get 404 with welcome page with Symfony 6 even with APP_ENV=prod